# Oracle 12c in Docker

Tags: oracle, docker

For a while I'm searching for a good way to run Oracle in Docker. It was always ending up in huge images, and slow starting containers.

But today I saw the link: https://store.docker.com/images/oracle-database-enterprise-edition

Is this just an official Oracle12c we can use (I was able to pull and start it) or is this only for enterprise users?

Can I customize this image with my own .sql scripts? (With some entrypoint)?

Comment: It is an official Oracle database. You can legally use it if you have existing Oracle Enterprise Edition license. Otherwise you can use it if you agree to abide by [the standard Oracle download licence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html). Basically if you don't have an EE licence you can't use the Docker image for any commercial purpose (i.e. as a Production instance) but you can use it for development and testing *until your application goes live* (then you need to licence your development environment as well as production). Warning: I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Cool thanks, do you know if it's possible to provide .sql scripts during startup/ image build? (like entrypoint for mysql, postgres, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow the following steps:**

1. docker login
2. docker pull store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
3. docker run -d -it --name oracledb12c -P store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
4. docker port containerID 1521/tcp (you will can connect to the datbase outside of the container using this port)

`$ docker ps #check while the container status is not healthy)`

- Connect with sqlplus
  docker exec -it containerID bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"
- Connect with jdbc:
  USER: sys   PASSWD: Oradoc_db1
  jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=127.0.0.1)(protocol=tcp)(port=portNumner))
  (connect_data=(service_name=ORCLPDB1.localdomain)))